# Error Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Tags: javascript

So, I try to make a website so when you click a button it shows a text saved in the same folder with the .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="site">
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Obtener texto</button>
</div>
<script src = "libraryxhr.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

And the .js 

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function loadDoc() {
  xhr.open("GET", "Prueba.txt", true);
  xhr.send();
  document.getElementById("site").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
```

It won't load the file; when I press f12 on my browser is shows nothing, but when I press the button, the check thing shows an error in the send() method, saying: "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https"

I am using Ubuntu17.04, just in case.

Comment: How are you loading the html file? Straight from the filesystem? Meaning your url is file:///...? If so that is the problem you cannot use XHR to get local filesystem files.

Comment: Yes, I just open my HTML file as a local file, it shows in my browser as "file:///home/juanpimentelx/Desktop/Web/XHR/xhr.html". it is such a shame I can't do this

Comment: You can still get the file, it just requires user interaction to get it, either through a file input <input type="file"> or drag and drop operation. Just cant do it by ajax unless you serve them through a server.

Comment: so, what I am missing is <input type="file"> andd add Prueba.txt to it, then the function loadDoc() would get the value of the input instead of the file in my computer?

Comment: No, you cannot programmatically set a <input type="file">. You put the input, then you (or whatever user) would click browse and select the file from your computer. You cannot programmatically get a user's files from the browser without some interaction from them.

Comment: I see, I already solved the problem thanks to you. Thank you very much